# What does the word 'there' refer to?

Tags: word-meaning, usage

> The medico went to the nearest village and there in the bazaar he found various kinds of meat and fish.

In this sentence,what does the word 'there' refer?why?

Comment: "There" is a locative pro-form, i.e. it's being used anaphorically to refer  to "the nearest village". It's used to avoid repetition of the antecedent. It's actually optional here; dropping it would not change the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

"There" in this sentence refers to "in that place".
It is providing emphasis on the location, possibly denoting that such things were not available elsewhere.
However, the sentence will still make sense without the word.

Comment: *There* **means** "in that place", but it **refers to** "the village".

Comment: The meaning is ambiguous. *there* could also refer to a location "in the bazaar" where he found stuff.

Comment: StoneyB is correct IMO that "there" does refer to the village. Otherwise if "there" was referring to the bazaar, the sentence would be "...village and in the bazaar there he found..."